# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, while not accessing any of the index

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

For some reason I am getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error, I am not trying to access any of the elements of the array, all I want to do is set the size, and pass by reference to the i.getRGB().

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Logic;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author Steven, even(RageZone), Zingzags(PokeCommunity)
 */
public class SpriteSheet {

    private String path;
    private final int size;
    private int[] pixels;

    public static SpriteSheet tiles = new SpriteSheet("/Tilesets/Outside.png", 256);

    public SpriteSheet(String path, int size){
        this.path = path;
        this.size = size;
        pixels = new int[this.size * this.size];
        load();
    }

    public int getPixels(int params){
       return pixels[params];
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }

    public int[] getPixels(){
        return pixels;
    }

    private void load(){
        try{
            BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResource(path));
            int w = im.getWidth();
            int h = im.getHeight();
            im.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
    Exception in thread "Display" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Logic.Sprite.<clinit>(Sprite.java:16)
    at Logic.Screen.render(Screen.java:46)
    at game.Game.render(Game.java:82)
    at game.Game.run(Game.java:109)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65536
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:958)
    at Logic.SpriteSheet.load(SpriteSheet.java:47)
    at Logic.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:27)
    at Logic.SpriteSheet.<clinit>(SpriteSheet.java:21)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For some reason I am getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error, I am not trying to access any of the elements of the array, all I want to do is set the size, and pass by reference to the i.getRGB().

According to the javadoc for the [`getRGB(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method:

> *"An ArrayOutOfBoundsException may be thrown if the region is not in bounds. However, explicit bounds checking is not guaranteed."*

---

As to the cause of the exception, I think that the problem is that the `pixels` array isn't big enough to hold the region of the image you are trying to extract to it.  There's no obvious correlation between `size` and the dimensions of the image you are reading.  (But then, it is not clear what you are actually trying to do in the `load` method ...)

Comment: The thing is that it is in bounds, it is not like I am going out of its parameters or anything. But what are you trying to say is a clear checking if the array is not in bounds is clearly depicted?

Comment: I'm trying to say that is is most likely caused by providing incorrect parameters to `getRGB`.  Precisely why they are incorrect is unclear ... and how to correct them depends on what you are actually trying to do.  (But you should be able to figure it out from reading the javadoc carefully.)

Comment: Why would changing `size` to a `long` make any difference?  That's unlikely to be the problem.  The problem is most likely the **value** you are using.

Comment: Oh okay! I just checked, and The values are passing where they are suppose to be (ignore the comment about long earlier).

Comment: They are all going in as integers. I checked everything the values are proper to the datatype, and the parameters of the method are where they are suppose to be.

Comment: I think you are still missing the point.  For instance (hypothetically) `-1` is proper for the datatype etc, but still completely wrong.  This is not about values being appropriate to the datatype.

Comment: I found the issue the parameters of the image was too big for the array.(I did not future-proof the code, I only made it for test purposes at the moment).